# Bot framework v4: error moving into next step

Tags: c#, botframework, waterfall

I want my bot to ask the user for a location. And when the user answer "Near me" the bot should continue to the next step and when the user answer "Somewhere else" the bot should ask the user for the specific location before moving to the next step. How ever I'm having an error in the bot emulator. When the user chooses "Near me" or "Somewhere else" it would not send.

```
namespace FinancialPlannerBot.Dialogs.RealEstate
{
public class MainRealEstateDialog : WaterfallDialog
{
    public MainRealEstateDialog(string dialogId, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null) : base(dialogId, steps)
    {
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt",
               new PromptOptions
               {
                   Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Would you like to buy or rent?"),
                   Choices = new[] {new Choice {Value = "Buy"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Rent"}
                   }.ToList()
               });
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {              

            var buyOrRent = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
            var state = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
            state.BuyOrRent = buyOrRent.Value;

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt",
               new PromptOptions
               {
                   Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("What kind of real estate do you want?"),
                   Choices = new[] {new Choice {Value = "Type 1"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Type 2"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Type 3"}
                   }.ToList()
               });

        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var realEstateType = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
            var state = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
            state.RealEstateType = realEstateType.Value;

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt",
               new PromptOptions
               {
                   Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Which location are you considering?"),
                   Choices = new[] {new Choice {Value = "Near me"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Somewhere else"}
                   }.ToList()
               });
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => //ERROR
        {
            var nearOrSomewhereElse = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
            var state = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
            state.NearOrSomewhereElse = nearOrSomewhereElse.Value;

            if (state.NearOrSomewhereElse == "Somewhere else")
            {
                await stepContext.PromptAsync("textPrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Which location are you considering?")
                });
            }

            return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync();
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var nearOrSomewhereElse = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
            var state = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
            state.NearOrSomewhereElse = nearOrSomewhereElse.Value;

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt",
             new PromptOptions
                 {
                   Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply($"Please indicate the size of {state.RealEstateType}"),
                   Choices = new[] {new Choice {Value = "Size 1"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Size 2"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Size 3"}
                   }.ToList()
             });                    

        });

    }

    public static string Id = "MainRealEstateDialog";
    public static MainRealEstateDialog Instance { get; }= new MainRealEstateDialog(Id);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a couple problems here...

First, you'd need an if/else in the step that is dealing with the `"Near me"` vs `"Somewhere else"` because you only want to prompt in the case of the "Somewhere else", right?

Second, because that step is now going to return different results depending on the path taken, that next step needs to be ready to process to different incoming results. Right now that last step is bugged because it currently assumes it's going to receive a `FoundChoice`, but it won't. It would either be receiving the text from the `textPrompt` in the case of the `"Somewhere else"` path *or* it would receive nothing because of the manual `ContinueDialog` call. I'm actually not even sure that works, but, even if it does, it would be more "correct" to use the `WaterfallStepContext::NextAsync()` API to advance the waterfall instead. Take a look at the following changes to the third step for starters:

```
    AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => //ERROR
    {
        var nearOrSomewhereElse = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
        var state = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
        state.NearOrSomewhereElse = nearOrSomewhereElse.Value;

        if (state.NearOrSomewhereElse == "Somewhere else")
        {
            await stepContext.PromptAsync("textPrompt",
            new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Which location are you considering?")
            });
        }
        else
        {
          await stepContext.NextAsync();
        }
    });
```

Ok, now here would be the changes you'd need to make to the following step:

```
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var nearOrSomewhereElse = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context).NearOrSomewhereElse;

            // If it's somewhere else, then this step need to get the text value the person was prompted for in the previous step
            if(nearOrSomewhereElse.Value == "Somewhere else")
            {
               // Get the result of the text prompt from the previous step
               var whereExactly = stepContext.Result as string;

               // TODO: store the value in your state so you can reference it later in the final search
            }

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt",
             new PromptOptions
                 {
                   Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply($"Please indicate the size of {state.RealEstateType}"),
                   Choices = new[] {new Choice {Value = "Size 1"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Size 2"},
                                    new Choice {Value = "Size 3"}
                   }.ToList()
             });                    

        });
```

I should also point out that there are *MUCH* cleaner/simpler ways to do this without using the state accessors at all. You should really be storing intermediate values that you collect during the flow of your waterfall into the `WaterfallStepContext::Values` property instead.

Comment: The one with the //ERROR comment is giving an error. It says "Not all path returns a value in lambda expression of type waterfall" sir.

Comment: This line is giving an error too "var nearOrSomewhereElse = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["FPBotAccessors"] as FPBotAccessors).FPBotStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context).NearOrSomewhereElse;" It says state does not have a definition for NearOrSomewhereElse.